# Should CQRS Command perform a Query?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have `Customer`, `Order`, and `Product` Aggregate Roots... When the order is created, it takes in a `Customer` and a `List<Sales.Items>`. It looks something like:

```
public class Order
{
    public static Order Create(Customer customer, List<Sales.Item> items)
    {
        // Creates the order
        return newOrder;
    }
}
```

Then using CQRS I've created `OrderCreateHandler` which looks something like:

```
public class OrderCreateCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<OrderCreateCommand>
{

    public OrderCreateCommandHandler(ECommerceContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(OrderCreateCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var customerResult = // Q) Is it okay to execute a CustomerQuery here?

        var customer = new Customer(customerResult.Id, customerResult.FirstName, customerResult.MiddleName,
            customerResult.LastName, customerResult.StreetAddress, customerResult.City, customerResult.State, "United States",
            customerResult.ZipCode);

         //  blah....

         order = Order.Create(customer, products);
         _db.Orders.Add(order);
     }
}
```

My question is in the command handler, is it okay to perform queries to get the  data to build the aggregate roots I need to then pass? I don't ever store the aggregate root itself (just a reference if I need), but I don't want to pass in Ids and primitives everywhere, I want to follow SOLID OO and pass actual objects. Is this a violation of CQRS?

Comment: S == segregation.

Comment: Of course you can query your database in command handlers, however you should query your write side, not your read side. I.e. calling your `CustomerRepository#findById(id: CustomerId): Customer` is completely fine. Whether you should also be able to query your read side is for much longer discussion and depends on many variables, therefore I'm not going to go into the detail here.

Comment: @Ewan exactly. So now my confusion is how do I get that data? I could have a request with 20+ parameters, but this seems odd.

Comment: @Andy I'm not using repositories. Trying to move to a vertical slice architecture like in [Jimmy Bogard's Vertical Slice Architecture](https://vimeo.com/190925521)

Comment: You're probably taking some concepts from the lecture too literally. You need some data access layer to pull aggregates from your database into the memory. The repository pattern is usually the one which is the most flexible and therefore recommended. Just because you're packaging by feature and not by layer does not mean you cannot have repositories either. Just create a customer repository and use that to fetch a customer instance using an attribute defined by you.

Comment: put all the data you need in the command object

Comment: @Ewan watching the video again and Jimmy talks about that very thing, but couldn't that result in a lot of parameters being passed?

Comment: why do you think that is bad?

Comment: I'm asking myself something similar. In my command handler, I want to instantiate an aggregate and the values I need are in a read-only data store/cache built from other microservices. Do I model this read-only data as an aggregate even though its read-only or do I just execute "queries" in the command handler for it? Any advice?

Comment: @Ewan: Separation does not necessitate a lack of interaction, be it direct or indirect. Layer separation does not prevent one layer consuming the other.

Comment: @Flater its Segregation and they are not layers, if you command calls a query then its performance is bound to the query side of things and vice versa

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's start with a short review of the problem-space here. The fundamental benefit of adopting a CQRS *pattern* is to solve/simplify your problem domain by reducing the interleaving and leakage that begins to occur when utilizing the same model for your write-side as your read-side. Often, the tension that arises serves as a detriment to both. CQRS seeks to relieve this tension by separating (decoupling logically and possibly physically) the write-side and read-side of your system. With the above in mind it should be clear that neither your commands nor queries should be coupled to a logical entity from the other "side".

Given the above, we can now formulate a direct answer to your question: Yes, you can query your data store within a command handler **provided** the query is issued against your command model. Because your `OrderCreateCommandHandler` is part of the command model of your application, we want to avoid coupling it to any part of your read model. It's unclear whether or not this is case given the example code (although the name `CustomerQuery` does raise some suspicions).

More important than the answer above though is that... there is something else that *feels* fishy about the example you have provided. Can you feel that too?

What I see here is quite a bit of coupling. Your handler is retrieving a `CustomerResult` (VO?), then breaking down all of it's data into another entity's constructor (`Customer`), then passing the `Customer` to a factory method of yet *another* entity. We have quite a bit of "asking" happening here. That is, we are passing around a lot of data in way that creates coupling.

Furthermore, the command handler doesn't "read" in a very declarative fashion (which is what we want to strive for). What I mean is that it's kind of hard to "see" what's happening in your method because there is so much plumbing getting in the way. I think we can come up with a more cohesive/declarative solution.

Given that the general "flow" of a command handler can be broken down into three simple steps:

1. Retrieve all data (domain model) necessary to carryout the use-case
2. Coordinate the data to fulfill the use-case
3. Persist the data

Let us see if we can come up with a simpler solution:

```
buyer = buyers.Find( cmd.CustomerId );

buyer.PlaceOrder( cmd.Products );

buyers.Save( buyer );
```

Ah ha! Much cleaner (3 simple steps). More importantly though, not only does the code above achieve your same goal, it does so without creating many dependencies between disparate objects as wells as functioning in a more declarative *and* encapsulated manner (we aren't "newing" anything or calling any factory methods)! Let's break this down piece by piece so we can understand "why" the above may be a better solution.

`buyer = buyers.Find( cmd.CustomerId );`

The first thing I've done is introduce a new concept: `Buyer`. In so doing this, I am partitioning your data *vertically* according to behavior. Let's let your `Customer` entity have responsibility for maintaining `Customer` information (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, etc.), and allow a `Buyer` to be responsible for making purchases. Because some `Customer` information needs to be recorded when a purchase is made, we will hydrate a `Buyer` with a "snapshot" of that data (and possibly other data).

`buyer.PlaceOrder( cmd.Products );`

Next we coordinate the purchase. The above method is where a `new Order` is created. An `Order` doesn't just appear out of nowhere right? *Something* must place it, so we model accordingly. What does this achieve? Well, the `Buyer.PlaceOrder` method provides a place *in your domain* to throw `BuyerNotInGoodStanding`, `OrderExceedsBuyerSpendingLimit`, or `RepeatOrderDetected` exceptions. By only creating an `Order` in the context of it's placement, we can enforce how an `Order` can come about. In your example, either your application-layer command handler or your `Order` factory method would have to be made responsible for enforcing each invariant. Neither is a good place for checking business rules. Additionally we now have a place to raise our `OrderPlaced` event (which will be necessary to keep your payment context decoupled), and also we can simplify your `Order` entity as it now only needs a scalar `buyerId` to keep reference to it's owner.

`buyers.Save( buyer );`

Pretty self-explanatory. A `Buyer` now contains all of the information you need to persist both an `Order` and a "snapshot" of `Customer` data. How you organize that data internally and take it apart for persistence is up to you (hint: A `Buyer` needn't be persisted at all, for example. Just the `Order` it contains).

**EDIT**

The example solution (if we can call it that) that I posted is one meant to get the "gears turning", and doesn't *necessarily* represent the best-possible solution to the problem at hand. That is, *your* problem. It is totally possible (even likely) that introducing the concept of a `Buyer` aggregate is over-engineering given that there had been no mention of any sort of rules regarding how an `Order` can be placed. For example:

```
customer = customers.Find( cmd.CustomerId );

order = customer.PlaceOrder( cmd.Products ); // raise OrderPlaced

orders.Save( order );
```

may be a totally valid approach! Just be sure to include all of the necessary information in the `CustomerInformationSlip` (your "snapshot") attached to the `Order` to allow it to enforce any invariant controlling how it can be modified. For example:

```
order.ChangeShippingAddress( cmd.Address ); // raise ShippingAddressChanged
```

The above may throw an `OrderExceedsCustomerShippingDistance` if each `Customer` has their own rules regarding how far you will ship to them given their account tier.

Let the rules dictate the design!

Comment: This might be one of the best answers I have ever seen about DDD aggregates. But my understanding of DDD leads me to believe that `Buyer`, in this case,  would be an AR and would be persisted. However, there is no `Order` repository which I thought would also be an AR.

Comment: I understand I most likely missed an AR and as you alluded to and also found at Udi Dahan's [blog](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/), you shouldn't just create an aggregate out of thin air. However, with minimal experience I would've called it something like `var order = customer.PlaceOrder(products); orders.save(order);`

Comment: @keelerjr12 You aren't wrong here. See my edit above.

Comment: What if the data that's used to create an aggregate is read-only data that comes from other microservices? Would you model that as an aggregate even though there is no behaviour? Or would you allow your commands to do a query to get that read-only data?

Comment: @fml Clarify "no behavior". Because an aggregate's responsibility is to act as a logical *consistency* boundary, I would hesitate to understand something with no behavior as a aggregate -- one can generally *read* data freely within a system. If you mean that this aggregate *uses* data but does not *change* that data, then we need to have a different discussion that involves refactoring our aggregate in a way such that we inject our data into the appropriate method instead of the constructor (e.g. `A(data); A.doSomething()` to `A(); A.doSomething(data)`). This looses our `data` dependency.

Comment: For something like OrderPlaced, it's implied that that represents an attempt to submit an order, correct?   So you'd have an OrderPlaced event with a subscriber that communicates with Paypal (or whatever transaction handling service you're using) and then that handler would set the status of the order based on the result from the service?

Comment: @maembe Your understanding is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it okay to perform queries to get the data to build the aggregate roots I need to then pass?

Are you worried about data races?

If you aren't worried about a data race, then you can safely use a stale copy of the real data, and CQRS really doesn't care all that much where the stale data comes from.

On the other hand, if a data race would be a problem, then you probably need to stop and rethink things.

In this *specific* case, you are probably fine to use a query; I guess that because you seem to be looking up customer information that you don't control -- what you are querying is information that is controlled by the real world.  So your data might already be wrong (the customer changed names, but you haven't gotten a notification yet).

Comment: No not really worried about a data race. I guess the issue would be re-hydrating the aggregates with the data I need. Like I said `Order` requires a List of Items and a `Customer` aggregate. So I need all the data to pass into the `Product` and `Customer` constructors before I pass those objects into the `Order` constructor (i.e. `Order.Create(new Customer(id, name, email, shipping address), items)`.

Comment: Why are you passing aggregates to the constructor of another aggregate?  _That_ is really suspicious.

Comment: Isn't that good OO? Pass a Customer object... `Order.Create(Customer, items)` vs `Order.Create(CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, Email, items)`..

Comment: And constructor was bad wording.. should be: pass aggregates into the methods of another aggregate e.g. `create` method inside `Order`.

Comment: It depends on what behaviors/capabilities your Order object needs to do its work.

Comment: it really just needs the data to be able to persist an order to the database.

Comment: Then just pass the data.

Comment: I'm uber-confused now.. Is it not okay to pass an aggregate root to another aggregate root? I obviously never store it except by reference, I don't modify it, so the only thing left to do is get some of it's data like in the case of `Order` requiring `Customer`'s data to persist from the order form.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86575/discussion-between-voiceofunreason-and-keelerjr12).