# Too strong of coupling between aggregate roots?

Tags: design, domain-driven-design

In an effort to save this question, I have re-written it. The original question was regarding how to associate aggregate roots. I have re-factored the code slightly but believe this may couple the code too tightly.

Do I introduce too tight of coupling by passing aggregate roots around? For example:

```
class Order
{
    public Order(int customerId, Address billing, Address shipping, List<Items> items)
    {
        _customerId = customerId;
        _billing = billing;
        _shipping = shipping
        _items = items;
    }

    private int _id;
    private Address _billing;
    private Address _shipping;
    private List<Item> _items;
}

class Customer
{
    public Order PlaceOrder(List<Item> items)
    {
        return new Order(_id, _billingAddress, _shippingAddress, items);
    }

    private int _id;
}

class Cart
{
    public Order Checkout(Customer customer)
    {
        var items = _items.ToList();
        _items.Clear();

        return customer.PlaceOrder(_items.ToList());
    }

    public AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        // Add item to cart
    }

    public RemoveItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        // Remove item from cart
    }

    private List<Item> _items = new List<Item>();
}
```

So then in my application service layer for a customer to checkout I would have something like:

```
public CustomerCheckoutService
{
    public void Checkout(int customerId)
    {
        var customer = _customerRepo.GetById(customerId);

        CompletePurchase(customer);
    }

    public void Checkout(int customerId, Address newShipping)
    {
        var customer = _customerRepo.GetById(customerId);

        customer.UpdateShipping(newShipping);

        CompletePurchase(customer);
    }

    private void MakePurchase(Customer customer)
    {
        var cart = _cartRepo.GetByCustomer(customerId);

        var order = cart.Checkout(customer);

        _orderRepo.Save(order);
        _cartRepo.Save(cart);
    }
}
```

I just feel like there is a lot of coupling between my aggregates with each one need each other.

Comment: Classic case of ‘down-vote and run’

Comment: They happen to be in in same bounded context, because they are supposed to be in same bounded context. Your understanding of what bounded context is and how it relates to aggregate roots is faulty.

Comment: In this case I understand they are in the SAME BC. I also gave the example of a Shopper and Customer which are in different BCs. I understand what a BC is. My question relates to more of the how to associate aggregates with a 1:1 mapping. When a Customer/Shopper is created I also need to create the associated Cart.

Comment: Let’s break this down further... Shopper and Cart are ARs in the Shopping BC. Cart has CartItems as part it’s Aggregate. In the Ordering BC, we have Customer and Order as ARs with Order consisting of OrderLines. When a shopper is created the associated Cart should also be created. Additionally when a Shopper checks out, this shopper needs to be associated with a customer so an order can be placed. This would be a better example that deals with associations between aggregates in different BCs as well as Aggregates in the same BC.

Comment: It helps to have a strong definitions for shopper, customer, etc.

Comment: @NoChance I have refactored the question.

Comment: I am not familiar with DDD but, I see that your customer class is not familiar. It has a place_order method that returns data from somewhere that is not clear. Anyway, this is not your question...

Comment: @NoChance it's using the customer information to create an order with the products that are passed into it from a customer's cart.

Comment: Not sure why your customer has the capability to create new Orders when there's already an OrderRepository. Looks like you are missing something between customers and orders. What does your Ubiquitous language say about the relationship between customers and orders?

Comment: @Laiv, we are trying to push more logic down into the domain and follow Udi Dahan's advice: [Don't Create Aggregate Roots](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/)

Comment: Additionally, I can create an order and inject customer's data without having to expose all his data. One issue I see is when a customer wants to ship to a different address than what he has listed.

Comment: I asked a question about this last night [HERE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/382472/274856)

Comment: @NoChance I have updated the `CustomerCheckoutService` to reflect the ability for a customer to change where the order would be shipped.

Comment: I think you have too many methods...MakePurchase, Checkout, PlaceOrder...You also have Shopper vs. Customer...I would create a scenario on paper first.

Comment: @NoChance completely agree that a `Shopper` aggregate should be in our design. However, I don't really think I agree with removing the method such as `PlaceOrder`. Sure I could just `new` up a new `Order` inside the service but then I'm basically left with a behavior-less `Customer` and an `Order` that was created out of thin-air. Keeping with the Ubiquitous Language, an Order is placed by a Customer. Finally, I would need to expose all the properties on `Customer` to get the data to pass to `Order` which seems to break OO encapsulation.

Comment: Personally, I stick to mapping ERD/DB Tables to Objects in 1-1 manner, I wish I could help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain looks okay here except that we know a `Cart` does not `CheckOut` itself. Right? `CheckOut` represents more of a use-case than it does any one specific data mutation. "Checking out" is a *process* with which a `Customer` engages as a means to conduct some business transaction (`PlaceOrder`). As such, it makes more sense to keep this piece of knowledge in your application layer. Furthermore, often different ways/kinds of "checking out" begin to arise as a business develops.

Your service can be simplified to something like:

```
// CheckOutCommandHandler

purchaseRequest = purchaseRequests.Find( cmd.CustomerId )

customer = customers.Find( cmd.CustomerId )

order = customer.PlaceOrder( purchaseRequest ) // raise OrderPlaced

orders.save( order )
```

Given you have `Cart` and `Customer` in different bounded contexts, we do indeed need to introduce a new concept in your Order context that can hold the information necessary to `PlaceOrder`. In this case I've name it `PurchaseRequest`.

At it's core, I think your uncertainty is founded on some confusion regarding *how* the different entities you are working with relate to one another. Specifically, how your Shopping and Order contexts can share data with one another. This is resulting in the passage of more data around than necessary and a lot of double-dispatch (both forms of coupling).

It's critical to understand that your *data* model (your database) has no concept of "bounded contexts". This is makes sense because a database has no behavior (which is how bounded contexts are organized). The result of this is that a `Cart` and a `PurchaseRequest` are hydrated using the *same* data! The difference is that a `Cart` represents a Shopping context entity which is responsible for adding/removing items, and a `PurchaseRequest` represents an Order context value object that is *copied* into a new `Order` when placed. Additionally, it could be a place to hold an alternate shipping address, coupon codes, etc.

Comment: whoa... So you could have 2 different entities referencing the same table? Logically they're different, but physically the same? *Mind-blown*. What if you had a database/store for each BC (like commonly recommended)? The implementation would require that data be duplicated. Additionally, we have the invariant that when an `Order` is placed, the `Cart` should be emptied.. I assume you would handle this with a Domain Event such as `CustomerOrderPlaced` to which a `Cart` would subscribe?

Comment: I think our issue is that we are trying to map our domain models to our database tables 1:1 and it's really causing confusion in our implementation. But in this case a `CartItem` and `PurchaseOrder` could be mapped to the same `LineItem` table.

Comment: @keelerjr12 It's true that it's usually not a good idea to "share" data between entities, but this is a very specific case regarding our `Cart` and `PurchaseRequest`. They aren't sharing so much as *copying*. Think of it like this, any other implementation is going to look something like: `pr = new PurchaseRequest( cart.ToList() )` anyway (which is essentially the same thing as hydration from the DB with more coupling). Somehow someway, the contents of the `Cart` need to be retrieved and copied into an `Order`. This simply must occur.

Comment: @keelerjr12 Hydrating different Entities with the same data is totally valid **provided** only one of those Entities holds invariants and allows for the data to be changed. Conceptualizing Value Objects for message passing is not only extremely useful, it is sometimes necessary. And yes, use your `OrderPlaced` event to empty the `Cart`.

Comment: let's say that you chose not to "copy" the data and you have to do what you just talked about. In that case you are `new`ing up a new object. Is it because it's near the BC boundary or because `PurchaseRequest` is a VO that you are okay with `new`ing up a new object (which goes against the advice of Udi Dahan in his post [Don't Create Aggregate Roots](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/)?

Comment: @keelerjr12 Well, we aren't creating an Aggregate Root! In any case, don't take his advice to be gospel. You have to design *your* system. If for some reason, you would rather query your `Cart` and have it expose it's `List` to a VO, then go for it. Prioritize quantity over quality. Once you have a *feel* for how things should look/work, you will find the former results in more quality anyway.